# get area edges with a point, a vector and 2 distance

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I am doing an app where I have to draw a zone where I an object can flight.

I need to draw that zone using Cesium (a JS library for world-class 3D globes) under the shape of a polygon, so only extremity points.

At the moment, my flight area are all Squares, and they are defined as follow

LL => LowerLeft Coordinate (POINT in lat/long)
Dir => Direction from LowerLeft (Vector director)
LLLR => Distance to LowerRight (Distance in meter)
LLUL => Distance to UpperLeft (Distance in meter)

[image]

So I have to draw a polygon that rotate based on the the dir like this

[image]

I tried various implementations, but I keep failing and not drawing the correct values. What I am doing is

```
 LowerLeft = {LL.x, LL.y, LL.z}
 LowerRight = {LL.x + LLLR , LL.y, LL.z}
 ProjectedLowerRight = Project LowerRight onto Dir
 UpperLeft = {LL.x, LL.y + LLUL, LL.z}
 ProjectedUpperLeft = Project UpperLeft onto Dir rotated of 90°
 UpperRight = {LL.x + LLLR , LL.y + LLUL, LL.z}
 ProjectedUpperRight = Project UpperRight onto Dir rotated of 45°
```

then use those 4 coord

```
{
lowerLeft 
ProjectedLowerRight
ProjectedUpperLeft  
ProjectedUpperRight 
}
```

But I think my logic is wrong. What is the correct way to rotate an area, or to draw the area correctly ?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. If I read this correctly, you basically have a rectangle in three dimensional space, and you are trying to rotate it about its lower left corner, based on a vector "dir". What does not make any sense at all is what rotation you want (a completely incomprehensible diagram that you don't bother to explain does not help at all). How does "dir" indicate the orientation of the new rectangle?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Basically, I have 1 point LowerLeft, 2 distance (from LowerLeft to upperLeft and lowerRight) and a Direction. If I draw without direction, I will have a rectangle. 
The direction represent the direction of the vector LowerLeft to LowerRight, The distance is the magnitude of this vector so the distance separating LowerLeft to LowerRight. 

Dir is also the x axis of the coordinate system to draw the rectangle (so when this dir rotate the rectangle rotate

Comment: But you are showing 3 dimensions: $x, y, z$. A single vector is not enough to specify the orientation of the rectangle. Dir points towards the lower right corner, but what determines the direction of the upper left corner? It has to be perpendicular to Dir, but there is an entire plane of vectors with that property. If you hold a sheet of paper, you can rotate it 360 degrees about one edge, leaving that edge (Dir) unchanged. So Dir is not enough to determine how your rectangle is oriented.

Comment: There will be 3 direction in the future, but for the moment, and simplicity, i would like to execute it on only 2 direction x/y z will always be equal to 0, so all the the corner are the corner of the flat rectangle

Answer (score 1):

With the clarification, what you need to use is easy. If the length of Dir is the distance from LL to LR, (that is, $(\text{Dir.x})^2 + (\text{Dir.y})^2 + (\text{Dir.z})^2 = (\text{LLLR})^2$) you need to define just two new points:

```
NewLR = LL + Dir
NewUR = UL + Dir
```

That is,

```
NewLR = (LL.x + Dir.x, LL.y + Dir.y, LL.z + Dir.z)
NewUR = (UL.x + Dir.x, UL.y + Dir.y, UL.z + Dir.z)
```

And your 4 corners are:

```
LL, UL, NewLR, NewUR
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this